# Joomla call specific function from component to module

Tags: database, joomla

I just want to call a specific function in a component. From the RokGallery Component in com_rokgallery\lib\RokGallery\Model.file.php is a &createNew function that i need in a module. Did anyone know how I can call these from my module and gave them spec variables?
In components\com_rokgallery\lib\RokGallery\Job\Processor\import.php on Line 31 is something other that I think I need for these...

I hope someone can help me ....

Regards, Marvin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you can require the file and use the Class.
To do that you have to import the rokgallery library.

```php
$include_file = realpath(JPATH_ROOT . DS . 'components'. DS . 'com_rokgallery' . DS . 'include.php');

$included_files = get_included_files();
if (!in_array($include_file, $included_files) && ($libret = require_once($include_file)) !== 'JOOMLA_ROKGALLERY_LIB_INCLUDED') {
    JError::raiseWarning(100, 'RokGallery: ' . implode('<br /> - ', $loaderrors));
    return;
}
```

Once that you can use the static method createNew

```php
$file = RokGallery_Model_File::createNew($filename, $filepath);
```

Comment: Hey and thank you.. uhm I´m relative new in developing Modules/Components, Where should I put in this 2 snippets `? both in der mod_XXX/helper.php or mod_XXX/module.php
Thanks for your answer tho...

Comment: If you use it the first part in mod_xxx/xxx.php after defined('_JEXEC') or die; then you can use RokGallery_Model_File::createNew(); everywhere.